# CakePHP Form Validation rendering error

Tags: validation, cakephp, rendering

I was doing the standard CakePHP blog tutorial (using 2.4 beta since it'll be out of beta by the time I make a real site)

On the add form I'm seeing rendering issues, is this a bug or something I've done:-

The validation popup on the second field is messed up, resizable gap above it a bit like the multi line text input its attached to the validator on the first text box is fine

See the drag handle (top right of the popup)
http://snag.gy/U7tKQ.jpg

And you can drag it 
http://snag.gy/087fr.jpg

it seems to be connected to the fact the popup is on a field that is resizable

Comment: There is potential for the CakePHP CSS to be doing this though isn't there? (I'm using the out of the box "empty" project" and modifying that as per the tutorial and it's displaying like that in chrome. I see a fair bit of CSS in /css/cake.generic.css relating to form validation

Comment: if chrome was behaving correctly, there would be no post :)

Comment: @AD7six looks like you are right, I'm a little shocked that's in a release version of chrome, if you want to post it as an answer I'll accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### That's chrome's default behavior

The framework used to generate the form won't affect the appearance of that kind of message. Chrome's default behavior (or simply, behavior - don't think it can be modified) for any input with `required="required"` is to prevent submitting the form if the input is empty with a hint of `Please fill in this field` (or similar). This is one of the many features introduced in [html5 capable browsers](http://john.foliot.ca/required-inputs/).

[image: Chrome will prevent submitting empty fields with a popup displaying "Please fill in this field"]

### js interference?

The mentioned drag handles on the hint popup are not normal - that is likely caused by some javascript or a browser extension.

Answer (score 1):

Go there http://diveintohtml5.info/forms.html and scroll down to form validation.

This is HTML5 built in form validation for the browser you're using, inspect the input element. Honestly I'm not sure if you can style them different but to me it looks like the browser is doing this by adding some markup and CSS to the DOM tree that might conflict with whatever else you have there. I personally haven't had the case before.

Knowing your markup and CSS might help by the way.